# Catalog filters

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

I have matched my attributes as

```
'is_filterable' => true,
'is_filterable_in_search' => true,
```

Is functionality of filtering in catalog on frontend available out-of-box? I  was searching around adminhtml for some configuration to turn it on and I haven't found anything. Do i need write module? Or maybe someone has something he can advice - some paid extensions?

**edit**

This is whole installation of one of atributtes that products should be filtered by.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'supported_software',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'frontend_class' => 'required-entry',
                'label' => 'Supported software',

                'group' => 'Technical parameters',
                'sort_order' => 190,

                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'frontend' => '',
                'source' => '[company_name]\DbSchema\Model\SupportedSoftware\Adminhtml\Source\SupportedSoftware',

                'default' => 10,

                'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,

                'used_for_sort_by' => false,

                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,

                'searchable' => false,
                'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                'search_weight' => '',
                'is_filterable' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_search' => true,
                'is_comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'downloadable,bundle',
                'is_used_for_promo_rules' => true,

                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,

                'is_required_in_admin_store' => '',
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit generic.

Yes the layered navigation is available out-of-box, to see it you need to have a filterable category assigned to a product. If you're adding a custom attribute programatically, ensure you set the 'system' property to 0, otherwise you will not be able to see the attribute within the layered navigation.

If you're having any further issues, be specific in what you have tried previously and in what way the layered navigation is not working for you.

Comment: I don't see layered navigation (I mean these filters on the left) at all. What do you mean - filterable category? How can I check if my category is filterable? I will try to implement your advices and I will write back about results.

Comment: To add an attribute to the layered navigation you must enable it using the property "Use in Layered Navigation". This should be set to "Filterable (with results). You then need to add this attribute to a product, and select one of the options available so that the layered navigation filter would return results. Note: you can only add attributes to the layered navigation if they're of type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price

Comment: I have edited my question